# How do I pass a parameter with slash in a ServiceStack route?

Tags: c#, servicestack

My requirement is to pass a value, as a parameter, in a ServiceStack route which includes a slash like this '**SK-LOT-79-14/3/11'** so I can fetch the records in my service.

Example route configuration:

```cs
[Route("/cims/qcHistoryByLot/{lotNumber}", "GET")]
```

Example lot number: SK-LOT-79-14/3/11

Comment: Please show the source code and a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: Search a bit, before posting to SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658119/servicestack-pass-forward-slash-in-uri

Comment: The scenario @Log1c has linked to is different, because the linked question wanted to use a `/` in the middle of routes, and therefore required a complex solution. This question can be easily supported by wildcard paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to add a `*` to the end of your route parameter.

```cs
[Route("/cims/qcHistoryByLot/{lotNumber*}", "GET")]
public class GetQcHistoryByLot
{
    public string LotNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Using the asterisk `*` acts as a wildcard and will capture anything after `/cims/qcHistoryByLot/` into `LotNumber`. See [wildcard paths in the routing documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#wildcard-paths) for more information.

This will work for routes where you are passing the slash in the last route parameter. If you require to pass a slash in a parameter that does not come last on the route, then you will need to handle encoding the value. [See my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659147/1295344).

Comment: Thank's Scott thanks a lot working fine and if u have any documents or reference links on service stack please share to my mail id vasu0020@gmail.com.

Comment: @srinu You're welcome. The official documentation [can be found here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki#documentation) it's very useful for getting started. Good luck with your project, and welcome to SO.